# Django filter year, ww and day between two dates

Tags: django-models

I have object with year, ww and day fields, I want to pull the data within date range.

Something like this code:

```
myObject.objects.filter(Year__range=(from_date, to_date), WW__range=(from_date, to_date), Day__range=(from_date, to_date))
```

But, this code is not woking for me, because each range depends on another one (ww depends on year).
Is there any way to marge year, ww and day to date in filter query, or suggest other solution?

Comment: Are you trying to fetch all the entries between two dates?

Comment: ww is weak, I can create a date with year, weak and day, but I don't want to get all data from myobject and after do the filter between two date, I want get only the expected data from myobject

Comment: Can you give me your date format and models?

Comment: have you try this `myObject.objects.filter(dateColumn__range=(start_date, end_date))`?

Comment: but I don't have one column date, I have three field that include date time: year, ww (weak), and day, there is way to unite them in filter level?

Comment: No, I don't think so you have apply filter on different fields only as you have done.

Comment: The code that a wrote is not ok, because each range depends on another one (ww depends on year), do you have another solution?

Comment: I think better way is to create one dateField of format `yyyy-ww-dd` and compare it, anyways you are filtering on all three fields at a time and you can categories week on the basis of date also.

Comment: you are rigth, but I can't change the DB

Comment: Then may be you can use `Q function ` to check the dependency with filter . Can you tell me what output you are expecting and what are the database value you have ?

Comment: Sumthing like this `myObject.objects.filter(Q(Year__range=(from_date, to_date)) & Q(WW__range=(from_date, to_date) & Day__range=(from_date, to_date)) & Q(Day__range=(from_date, to_date)))`

Comment: thx, I will check it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128927/discussion-between-sari-k-and-piyush-s-wanare).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the complete code, it's work well, thank Piyush for the good way!

MyObject.objects.filter(
    (Q(Year__gt=from_year) | (Q(Year=from_year) & (Q(WW__gt=from_ww) | (Q(WW=from_ww) & Q(Day__gte=from_day))))) &
    (Q(Year__lt=to_year) | (Q(Year=to_year) & (Q(WW__lt=to_ww) | (Q(WW=to_ww) & Q(Day__lte=to_day))))))